# Writing java script common function in RunnerTest.jave in Karate framework

Tags: javascript, json, grafana, influxdb, karate

I am working on Karate framework and have created multiple feature files.

In each feature there is common java script function 
This function insert the specified data to influx DB

My feature file looks something like this

```
    #####################################################
          @API Name
    Feature: API test

    #####################################################################################
            Background:
        * def DbUtils 
      * def config 
        * def db 

        * def 
        * def db
        * configure afterScenario = 
java script function to insert code to DB    
"""
    function(){
      var info = karate.info; 
      karate.log('after', );
      karate.log('after', );
      karate.log('after', );
      karate.log('after', );
      karate.log('after', );
      var featurenameupdate = info.featureFileName.substring();

      var status="Fail";
      if(!info.errorMessage == null){
        status="Pass";
      }
      dbCDB.DBConnection( );
      dbCDB.DBwrite(  );
      dbCDB.connectionClose();
    }
    """

    Scenario Outline: <scenarioNm>
    * def req = read('')

    * set req.param.param.id = 
    * set req.param.param.param = 


    #Building the authentication request, storing cookie and response validation

    Given url <<URL>>
    And request req
    When method method
    Then status status code
    Then match response.error
    <<error response>>
```

Is it possible? How can this be achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of use-case where I recommend using Java interop. Please write a custom Java utility that can perform this setup and it will be much easier to maintain and debug also. Then you can easily call it from anywhere.

Refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

This specifc example uses JDBC: [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature)